# Does exist Eclipse deployment assembly log?

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, deployment

I have project that contains many dependencies - several hundreds jars.
For debug run on Tomcat (Debug as > Debug on Server). The problem that sometimes some jars not deployed in tomcat work directory. May be exists log of deployment or something else that can helps to understand the reason?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you view the standard Tomcat catalina log file within the Eclipse window?

This is also visible by writing it into a file.

In the `Servers` tab, double-click on the Tomcat Server. You will get a screen called `Overview`.

Click on "`Open launch configuration`" in the middle of the screen. Click on the "`Common`" tab.

Towards the middle of the screen under "`Standard Input and Output`" you can check the "File" checkbox and then specify a file location that can be used to log your console output.

Restart the server and see if you have your logs.

Comment: This log does help nothing for deployment assembly